# jQuery count cm on page scroll - counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found many plugins counting up and down, but I am looking for something more interesting:

I have a HTML page 70.000cm high, I want to put a counter in a corner which will show the height you are at as you scroll down.

A Fiddle seemed pointless, if someone has encountered a plugin or has a slight idea of where to start, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: _A Fiddle seemed pointless_ NO That would be nice if you have tried something.

Comment: How do you propose to measure centimeters on a page? You cannot presume x pixels = y centimeters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.fn.calc_height();
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $.fn.calc_height();
        });
    });

    $.fn.calc_height = function() {
        var window_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var window_scroll_top_cm = window_scroll_top * 0.026458333;
        $('.currentheight').html( window_scroll_top_cm.toFixed(2) + ' cm' );
    };
    </script>

    <style>
    body { height:264566.92913386px; background:#666; text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    .currentheight { position:fixed; top:20px; left:20px; background:#FFF; color:#000; padding:10px 20px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="currentheight">asd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  $('div').html(($('body').scrollTop() * 0.026458333).toFixed(2) + 'cm');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/omqjec0h/)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this simple line of code and build the required amount of logic and programming around this. Its based on jQuery builtin function animate, first parameter contains options and the second is a time for that particular animation you try.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```

Cheers :)

Comment: I am using this to direct the user to the bottom of the page:
       $(function() {  $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());});

and as they scroll up it should count